# How to fill TextInputLayout with EditText fully?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

[image]

I have the EditText which is within `TextInputLayout`.
What I'd like to achieve is to have `EditText` fully within `TextInputLayout` to get rid of that blank space in the top of the edit field.

Here's the layout:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/login_edit_style"
        android:hint=" "> <!--android:hint=" "> if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mHint)) evaluates to false, and the EditText retains its hint.-->


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.17"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/field_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textColor="#4A4A4A"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_colour"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_edit_style"
        android:hint=" "> <!--if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mHint)) evaluates to false, and the EditText retains its hint.-->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_locker"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_show_pass"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.17"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/field_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textColor="#4A4A4A"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_colour"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That space at the top is for the floating label that appears when the user focuses on the EditText, like this:

[image]

If you don't want that floating label, switch to just using an `EditText`. Also, if you're using `TextInputLayout`, you should be using `TextInputEditText` inside it rather than just `EditText`.